# How to Name Deferred (Yielding) vs Regular IEnumerable<T> Extension Methods?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, naming

Is there a standard practice for adding a proper *suffix* or *prefix* to the names of `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods if they are *derred* as opposed to being immediately executable. This is desired so the user of a method immediately knows if it will be executed deferred or not.

Example (only to illustrate the point and explain what I am talking about, dont; consider these to be actual exact methods that are used in code):

```
public static IEnumerable<TOut> DoSomething<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> items, Func<TIn, TOut> transform) {
  var list = new List<TOut>();
  foreach (var item in items) {
    list.Add(transform(item));
  }
  return list;
}

public static IEnumerable<TOut> DoSomethingDeferred<TIn, TOut>(this IEnumerable<TIn> items, Func<TIn, TOut> transform) {
  foreach (var item in items) {
    yield return transform(item);
  }
}
```

In the above example, I added *Deferred* suffix to designate that a method does not immediately return. However I am not happy with such naming, is there a better way, a convention or best practice?

Comment: Consider that trouble coming up with a good name is a code smell.  It does too much and it is dangerous.  Including DontEverUseBreak in the name would be appropriate advertising but you are only going to find out after a while.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't quite get how coming up with a good name is a code smell? On the contrary it would improve readability and maintenance because it makes it very clear what the method does. It would also speed up development because consumers of such utility methods will be able to tell at a glance how they behave and select the one that is most appropriate for the use case.

Comment: I tend to go with "Iterate" as a prefix (i.e. "IterareTransform") for iterator functions (containing yield) and "Get" for things that give me ready made collections.  Also, I tend to return the least limiting interface that conveys what I've given (i.e. `IList<T>` if it makes sense for the user to add to it or `IReadOnlyList<T>` if I've made T's constructor internal or am sure the returned list is all inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an "official" convention for naming such methods. Any convention will have to be defined by you (like you've done) and communicated to your team.

That said, there are two simpler ways to still achieve your goal without having to define anything:

1. As a convention, distinguish them by return type. All your immediately executed methods' implementation will typically be packaging a known datatype to return; e.g `List<T>`/`IList<T>`, array, `HashSet<T>`, etc. Simply return that type. This way, once an API's return type is `IEnumerable<T>`, the consumer will know it's deferred execution; otherwise, it's immediate execution.
2. Put a comment on the methods. (You ought to be doing this already). In that comment, simply add a short note telling the user whether the method is immediately executed or deferred.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. However #1 wouldn't work well with Intellisense and overload resolution (methods would need to have either different parameter signatures or names). Comments are of course nice and are incouded but I was specifically looking for a naming suggestion (Deferred is just an example which I do not like as it is too long).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the standard LINQ operations, you will see that there isn't usually a deferred version and an immediate version of the same operation, you will see that things that can be done deferred (`Where`, `Select` etc), are done deferred. The basic rule is, if something can be done deferred, do it deferred.

Typically, it is pretty clear what is deferred and what is not. If it returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, it is very possibly deferred. If it returns something else, it can't be deferred.

So I'd say that you don't need a suffix or prefix and I don't think there is a "standard" one either. You don't need them anyway since it's rare that you will have to write 2 versions of the same method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there are some cases where you want to have both versions. And sometimes it is not clear which is which. The example I gave is just an example - a bit contrived - and is only to illustrate the point.

Comment: @FitDev if you really feel like you need two methods, name it `XXXDeferred` or anything else you and your team agree on. There isn't a standard as far as I know.